# Writing a program where the user the radius of a circle as an integer and prints the circle’s diameter, circumference and area

Tags: java

I wrote out this program, however, I don't know where my error is. When I try to run it on DOS, I get this error:

> Unit2Circle.java:26: error: variable radius is already defined in
>   method main(String[])         int radius =  input.nextDouble();
>             ^ Unit2Circle.java:26: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int      int radius =  input.nextDouble();

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Unit2Circle{  // class header

        public static void main(String[] args){ // main method header
            // To create a Scanner object
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // To declare variables, including radius, diameter, circumference and area
        double radius, diameter;
        double circumference, area;

        // To ask user to enter a number for the radius

        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");

        int radius =  input.nextDouble();

        diameter = 2*radius;
        circumference = 2*Math.PI*radius;
        area = Math.PI*radius*radius;

        // To print out diameter, circumference and area

        System.out.println("The diameter is " + diameter);
        System.out.println("The circumference is " + circumference);
        System.out.println("The area is " + area);



    } //end of main

}  // end of class
```

Can someone please explain to me the error and how to correct this? I want to write an application that inputs from the user the radius of a circle as an integer and prints the circle’s diameter, circumference and area using the floating-point value 3.14159 for π. Keep 3 floating digits for the output.

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: You are trying to compile this program, not run it, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the same variable twice, in the same method, which in Java is not allowed.

```
// To declare variables, including radius, diameter, circumference and area
double radius, diameter;                 // <<-- HERE
double circumference, area;

// To ask user to enter a number for the radius

System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");

int radius =  input.nextDouble();        // <<-- HERE
```

Probably, that last line should just be `radius = input.nextDouble();` without the word `int` at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you very much, Markspace. This just proves how horrible I am at paying attention to detail. I also didn't know that about input.nextDouble(), I will remember that in the future. Thank you very much, the program works now. I appreciate your time in helping me. Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing to do is figure out where your error is. The error message shows you that the problem is happening in the line that says:

```
int radius =  input.nextDouble();
```

There are two issues with this line: First, the variable `radius` is already defined in the main method. Look back in your code; you already defined `radius` earlier in the program, on this line:

```
double radius, diameter;
```

You defined `radius` not as an integer, but as a double!

When you wrote `int radius` you are telling the compiler that you want to make a new variable named radius that is an integer, but you've already told it to know when it sees `radius` to treat it as a double. Reading through your code, I think this `int` is an error, and that you want `radius` to be a double.

This also is the source of the second error: `input.nextDouble()` returns a double, and you're trying to store it into an `int`. So if you get rid of `int`, you'll solve both error messages.

Comment: Thank you very much, Davy. This just proves how horrible I am at paying attention to detail. I also didn't know that about input.nextDouble(), I will remember that in the future. Thank you very much, the program works now. I appreciate your time in helping me. Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score -1):

You defined radius twice, one as double, one as integer. When Java tried to define radius as integer, Java found a variable with same name is already defined as double and it doesn't like it.

Answer (score -1):

you have declared the variable radius two times where it should be once .let it be double so that the other values can output double as well because pi contains floating point numbers.